# How To Install Youtube-DL Graphical User Interface On Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: software-installation, youtube-dl

I Did The Following Commands :

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install youtube-dlg
```

Result :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package youtube-dlg
```

Comment: That PPA (https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8?field.series_filter=focal) doesn't provide what you're after for Ubuntu 20.04 so adding that source was of no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gydl (Graphical Youtube-dl) open terminal and copy and paste:

```
sudo snap install gydl
```

**When using Gydl, you have the option to download your YouTube video as a Video or Audio.**

Answer (score 5):

Gydl (Graphical Youtube-dl) is a GUI wrapper around the already existing youtube-dl program. To install Gydl in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install gydl
```

When using Gydl, you have the option to download your YouTube video as a **Video** or **Audio**.

[image]

Comment: It Does not Look like the original one tho : https://i0.wp.com/www.linuxandubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/youtube-dl-downloader-linux.png?w=1400

Comment: I have completely unistalled snaps.. is there a .deb version available to install in ubuntu 20.04 ?

Comment: @pat Gydl isn't available as a .deb file in the PPA. Here's the [Gydl GitHub](https://github.com/JannikHv/gydl).

Answer (score 2):

You also can download it directly from their website, or by using the command:

```
wget https://youtube-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl
```

That will download a python file you can run, assuming you are dedicated to the command line version.

Comment: 451 Unavailable For Legal Reasons - Hamburg court block it, due to the fact that three unknown mouths singers complained that their bulge being downloaded somehow incorrectly. https://openjur.de/u/2466945.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the PPA does not have youtube-dlg for 20.04/Focal available (yet).  You can take a look at which packages are available for Focal by going to [https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8?field.series_filter=focal](https://launchpad.net/%7Enilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8?field.series_filter=focal).

Answer (score 1):

I have installed it in 2 different OS: (1.-)Kubuntu 20, and today (2.-)Linux lite 5.0.
here they explain it nicely, I needed to get 2 packages (it's all here)

https://www.fossmint.com/youtube-dlg-gui-app-for-youtube-dl-video-downloader/

I followed instructions from where it says:
"If you don’t care much for getting automatic updates then....pick up the latest .deb package"
so I downloaded the youtube-dlg package (#1)

Also I downloaded the "twodict" pack (package#2)
then, I installed python-twodict using "gdebi pack installer" once downloaded.

Again using "gdbi package installer",went to youtube-dlg installation by just right clicking, selecting, and confirming...

And there it is the nice squared GUI ready to work from Internet menu.

I hope it works for you 2, I am not very good explaining, but it is all there.
I used gdebi P. I. because it tells me when something is wrong, and if it's OK, it does the job
automatically for me (didn't write anything in the terminal, I am an ex-windows user) I grabbed it from synaptic pack mgr, or Discover pack inst. It works just nice.

Answer (score 0):

To install Youtube-DL Graphical User Interface On Ubuntu 20.04? follow these steps;

1. Run system update and upgrade command.
2. Install Python Twodict.
3. Download YouTube-DLG GUI Deb package.
4. Install YoutTube-DLG on Ubuntu 20.04.
5. Run the program's GUI.
6. How to use Youtube-DLG.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a [GUI](https://github.com/kanehekili/YoutubeDownloader) for the youtube-dl that supports single files as well as playlist.

It relies on the the latest youtube-dl, not the one provided by Ubuntu. Two small install scripts are provided.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but better late than never.

[This GUI](https://github.com/JaGoLi/ytdl-gui) is simple but woking surprisingly well for me.

You can find it in `Ubuntu Software` under the name `Youtube Downloader` (Black icon with a `V` like shape), or you can install it yourself using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mordec13/youtubedl-gui
sudo apt update && sudo apt install youtubedl-gui
sudo pip3 install youtube-dl
```

I hope this helps.

PS: I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS